# Python: getting the print not defined error, but print is in lower case

Tags: python, printing

```
Line 6:  def writeNewFile():
Line 7:    print("\n")

Line 48 is the function call:
Line 48:  writeNewFile()
```

When I run the App, I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/31E5B41D-CBC9-4498-86A0-64A4E722A263/Documents/inputFile.py", line 48, in <module>
    writeNewFile()
  File "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/31E5B41D-CBC9-4498-86A0-64A4E722A263/Documents/inputFile.py", line 7, in writeNewFile
    print("\n")
NameError: name 'print' is not defined
Pytho3IDE run end!
```

I am writing this App on an iPad running Mac iPad OS version 16.5.1, and am using the PYTHON3IDE App to run Python.

Everything was working fine, until it stopped. Can anyone figure out the issue, because I can’t.

I tried rewriting the module, but with the same error,

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to print a newline? if so you can simply type `print()`

If you are trying to print `\n` you can do `print("\\n")`

Comment: If `print("\n")` gives that error in this IDE, seems like `print()` would most likely do the same.

Comment: Willy, contrary to expectations, both print() and print(“\\n”) work.  Thanks for your help.